# Is it possible to use one script to move mulitple hrefs to a class without having to use nth-child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have a few divs that look like this:

```
<div class="Box">
    <img src=../image.jpg>  
    <div class="mask">
        <a href="link" class="Link">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Box">
    <img src=../image.jpg>  
    <div class="mask">
        <a href="link" class="Link">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Box">
    <img src=../image.jpg>  
    <div class="mask">
        <a href="link" class="Link">
    </div>
</div>
```

is it possible to take the hrefs and move them to the Box class without having to use nth-child in the script?

Comment: You want to move each link to it's parrent Box?

Comment: `take the hrefs and move them to the Box class` What do you mean by that sentence?

Comment: Yes, I want to move it to its parent's box. Sorry about the lack of clarity.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't make the .Box class a link itself?

Comment: @JoshSanger normally this box has 6 links when you hover over it. But the client requested that on mobile the box should have one main link. So I want to move the main link from the hover to the box

Comment: See my below suggested answer. No JS needed. Just make sure the link you want to be the mobile link has the class `.Link`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, in that case I would use a CSS only approach. Since your client wants it on Mobile anyways simple make the parent container position relative and make the link you want to be clickable position absolute with a higher z-index and make it fill the container like so:

```css
/*Demo styling */
.Box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
body > * + * {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

/*Suggested styling */
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .Box {
    position: relative;
  }
  .Box .Link {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="Box">
    <img src=../image.jpg>  
    <div class="mask">
        <a href="link" class="Link">
        <a href="link2">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Box">
    <img src=../image.jpg>  
    <div class="mask">
        <a href="link" class="Link">
        <a href="link2">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Box">
    <img src=../image.jpg>  
    <div class="mask">
        <a href="link" class="Link">
        <a href="link2">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you like to make the whole outer div area clickable.

I solved this as follows.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('[data-clickable-area]').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
   $(this).find('a').first().trigger('click');
  });
  $('[data-clickable-area] a').click(function (e) {
   // triggering the default handler of browser did not succeed
   window.location = $(this).attr('href');
   e.stopPropagation();
  });
 });
```

```css
 [data-clickable-area] {
   cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Box" data-clickable-area>
  <img src=../image.jpg>  
  <div class="mask">
   <a href="https://duckduckgo.com/" class="Link">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="Box" data-clickable-area>
  <img src=../image.jpg>  
  <div class="mask">
   <a href="https://duckduckgo.com/" class="Link">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="Box" data-clickable-area>
  <img src=../image.jpg>  
  <div class="mask">
   <a href="https://duckduckgo.com/" class="Link">
  </div>
 </div>
```

Only one link for every box is supported in my solution.